# getting an xml file with curl

Tags: php, curl, simplexml

I am getting the following xml file and load it to my database with simplexml with no problems

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,
    'http://www.opap.gr/web/services/rs/betting/availableBetGames/sport/program/4100/0/sport-1.xml?localeId=el_GR');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$xml = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

This is basicly a betting site and i want to get the odds for each game. That site every Tuesday and Friday updates that xml with the odds of the following 3 days.

My problem is that i want to get the xml for each day not all of them. I searched a bit and i found that the url for each specific day is something like that

```
http://www.opap.gr/web/services/rs/betting/availableBetGames/sport/program/4100/0/sport-1/#d-2644.xml?localeId=el_GR
```

So basicly the #d-2644 is the id for the specific day and it changes for each day. My problem is that although when i open the link in my browser i can see the xml file when i get it with curl i am getting the following error

```
Notice: SimpleXMLElement threw an exception. Start tag expected, '<' not found in bla bla on line 325
```

What am i doing wrong :(

Comment: Did you checked the format of the specific file, is it valid?

Comment: If you think the markup isn't going to be 100% valid, it's probably a good idea to use [`DOMDocument`](http://php.net/DOMDocument) in place of SimpleXML. It's usually less picky.